# How to send a string array to a COM PORT?

Tags: c#, serial-port

Once I have identified a serial port to communicate with on Windows 7 (using the `Win32_SerialPort WMI method`, how do you recommend sending a string array to it using c#? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What format does the receiving device require? What have you tried?

Comment: @voltagex it asks for a [gcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-code) which is an array of string giving instructions to the printer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `SerialPort` class, as described here on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx

A prototype available is `Write(string)`, which you can use in a loop for your requirements.